# Python faker and django models

Tags: python, django-models, faker

I'm trying to create sample data for my project, and I'm using faker to populate my database. The customer model i'm using has a field for tags, which is a comma separated list of values. For my faker script, I'm created a list and broke it down into a comma separated list, but the database won't except the value. Here is my code:

```
import os
# Configure settings for project
# Need to run this before calling models from application!
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'openroad.settings')

import django
# Import settings
django.setup()

from random import randint, choice
from dispatch.models import Customer
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()

my_word_list = [
'danish','cheesecake','sugar',
'Lollipop','wafer','Gummies',
'sesame','Jelly','beans',
'pie','bar','Ice','oat',
'group', 'octopus', 'noble',
'crocodile', 'gravel', 'excellent', 'destiny',
'bleeding', 'phenomena', 'downward'
]



def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        # Create Fake Data for entry
        fake_company = fakegen.company()
        fake_name = fakegen.name().split()
        fake_poc = fake_name[0] + ' ' + fake_name[1]
        fake_contact = randint(1111111111, 9999999999)
        fake_street = fakegen.address().split('\n')
        fake_city = fake_street[1].split(',')
        fake_state = fake_city[1].split()
        fake_zip = fake_state[1].split('-')
        fake_notes = fakegen.text()

        count = 0
        tag_count = randint(1, 4)
        tags = []
        while count <= tag_count:
            tags.append(choice(my_word_list))
            count += 1

        tags = ",".join(str(x) for x in tags)

        customer = Customer.objects.get_or_create(name=fake_company,
                                                    address1=fake_street[0],
                                                    city=fake_city[0],
                                                    state=fake_state[0],
                                                    zipcode=fake_zip[0],
                                                    poc=fake_poc,
                                                    contact=fake_contact,
                                                    notes=fake_notes,
                                                    customer_tags=tags
                                                    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Populating the databases...Please Wait")
    populate(1)
    print('Populating Complete')
```

Here is the traceback info:

```
Populating the databases...Please Wait
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_customers.py", line 63, in <module>
    populate(1)
  File "populate_customers.py", line 58, in populate
    customer_tags=tags
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 464, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 371, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 784, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 802, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1261, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1217, in build_filter
    condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 112, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/jboucher/anaconda3/envs/openroad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'oat,octopus,sesame,bar,beans'
```

Model.py:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    poc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer_tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please show your model.

Comment: Whoops. Forgot to add that. Edited original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customer_tags` is a Taggit manager field, which under the hood is a many-to-many relationship; you can't set it directly on the model but you need to use the [`.add` method](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.add).

```
customer, _ = Customer.objects.get_or_create(name=fake_company,
                                             address1=fake_street[0],
                                             city=fake_city[0],
                                             state=fake_state[0],
                                             zipcode=fake_zip[0],
                                             poc=fake_poc,
                                             contact=fake_contact,
                                             notes=fake_notes)
customer.customer_tags.add(tags)
```